# git rev-list -n 1 build/22.05.3128 20:28:33 fatal: ambiguous argument 'build/22.05.3128': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: shell, github, groovy, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline with multibranching concept. Recently we have migrated from GITLAB to GITHUB.
While creating an new branch with the existing deployed package now we are getting this error for some of the project.

[Prime_Application] Running shell script
20:28:33 + git rev-list -n 1 build/22.05.3128
20:28:33 fatal: ambiguous argument 'build/22.05.3128': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
20:28:33 Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
20:28:33 'git  [...] -- [...]'

Code for the Above step:

```
ansiColor('gnome-terminal') {
                timestamps {
                    ansiColor('gnome-terminal') {
                        COMMIT_ID_1 = sh(
                                script: "git rev-list -n 1 \"build/${BUILD_PKG_VER}\"",
                                returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()
```

This is working for some of the repos but majorly Its failing for all repos.

Answer (score 0):

The script is not getting the value of build/${BUILD_PKG_VER}. Because in my code it was not tagged. Make sure you have correctly tagging your build and again pushing the event.